# PKCS#11 Generate AES key

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#11, hsm

Hei,
The question is not really about Ncryptoki but i didnt know anywhere else to ask.. so if anybody can help please help me. 
Im tryng to generate AES key and heres the code what i have right now:

```
CK_MECHANISM keyGenMech = new CK_MECHANISM(CKM.AES_KEY_GEN);

CK_ATTRIBUTE[] template =
{
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.CLASS, CKO.SECRET_KEY),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.TOKEN, CK_BBOOL.TRUE),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.SENSITIVE, CK_BBOOL.TRUE),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.VALUE_LEN, 32),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.KEY_TYPE, CKK.AES),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.LABEL, "testAES".getBytes()),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.PRIVATE, new CK_BBOOL(bPrivate))
};
CryptokiEx.C_GenerateKey(session, keyGenMech, template, template.length, wrappingKey);
```

But this gives me a error:

```
C_GenerateKey rv=0x62 - key size range
```

Can anybody give me some idea where to go from here to solve this..

EDIT: Just for info - I have SafeNet HSM and im using java PKCS#11 wrapper called `jprov` what comes with SafeNet ProtectToolkit.

Comment: @this.josh, changing the CKA.VALUE_LEN didnt change anything. Still getting same error.

Comment: Is `CKA.VALUE_LEN` supposed to be in bits or bytes?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answere, `new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.VALUE_LEN, 32),` , the 32 in there has to be CK_ULONG value so when i do this:

```
LongRef l = new LongRef((long)32);

CK_ATTRIBUTE[] template =
{
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.CLASS,     CKO.SECRET_KEY),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.TOKEN,     CK_BBOOL.TRUE),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.SENSITIVE, CK_BBOOL.TRUE),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.VALUE_LEN, l.value),
    //new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.VALUE,     key),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.KEY_TYPE,  CKK.AES),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.LABEL,     "testAES".getBytes()),
    new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA.PRIVATE,   new CK_BBOOL(bPrivate))
};
```

Where `LongRef` is:

```
public class LongRef {

    public long value; 

    public LongRef(long l) {
        //compiled code
        throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @AviD, sorry for that. Two different computers and thats why i couldnt use the same. Would be nice if u could merge them.(To the t678) Thanks!