# Which type of Key Format is better for AES 256

Tags: c, embedded, aes

here i want to encrypt and decrypt files using `AES 256 Algorithm` than i have to provide Key for Encrypt the files and same key for decrypt the files.

So which Key is better for good performance and Security also?
Which type of Format of key i will use here so i can get more security.

Here i have to use same key in Encrypt and Decrypt.

So Any body please can suggest me the better suggestions for Key.

Comment: You should choose keys by security and not by performance.
Main key properties which impacts security is [key length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size#Symmetric_algorithm_key_lengths) and key randomness (that is more random key is more secure, because if for example key is just some known word - then whole crypto system is vulnerable to [dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack).

Comment: @0x69 Thanks For your Reply. So i have to write code for Key Generator

Comment: This question is terminally unreadable. What is the problem being solved? Are you asking what is the best way to store keys on disk? That's as close as I can come to deciphering what you're trying to say, but I'm really unsure.

Comment: You should choose a key of all zeroes. No one will ever guess it and it will make your algorithm run super-fast. Seriously, if you're asking these kinds of questions, you should probably delegate the task to someone who actually understands the task - otherwise you'll end up with a weak implementation.

Comment: Why is this tagged "embedded".  Even if it is for an embedded system, is that at all relevant to the question?

Comment: My suggestion is to use cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator for key generation. If you need to pass this key over non-secured environment is is better to RSA to encrypt the key itself.

Comment: And my suggestion is that you post your environment and library, possibly allong with some code the next time you ask a question like this. Then you could be pointed to the right method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) key is just a bunch of bits with no structure. An AES-128 key is 128 bits, which must be chosen randomly. An AES-192 key is 192 bits, an AES-256 key is 256 bits. There aren't any different types or formats of keys.

Most cryptography libraries will have a function to generate an AES secret key. For example, with a [PKCS #11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS11) interface, [call `C_GenerateKey` with the `CKM_AES_KEY_GEN` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661329/pkcs11-generate-aes-key). If the library doesn't have a specific function, use it to generate the required number of random bytes, for example [with `RAND_bytes` in OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580662/aes-encryption-key-generation-with-openssl).

Consult your cryptographic library's implementation for proper usage. In particular, a random number generator requires [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29) from its environment, make sure you are providing enough.