# Why isn't the encoded key equal to the original key?

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, aes

**Language:** C#, **Framework:** .NET Core 3.1

I am using encryption based on [AES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8).

**Research:**
[Key Format AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494869/which-type-of-key-format-is-better-for-aes-256)

> Gilles: An AES key is just a bunch of bits with no structure.

The Key and IV need to be stored since they are randomly generated each time and they are required for Encryption and Decryption.

I need to store it as a string for particular reasons, so I want to be able to convert a byte array to a string and backwards if needed using encoding.

The conversion happens using `UTF-8` encoding.

**My problem:**
I've put a breakpoint in my code and the contents of the byte array are clearly different from the original array. I've tried switching to other encoding formats but this also failed. In a nutshell, the data changed and this would result in being unable to decrypt a message because the AES key and IV would be incorrect.

**Update:**
The `UTF-8` conversion doesn't work when `keyBytes` doesn't contain valid utf8 data and the encoder will generate fallback data which causes the problem.

**Example:**

```
using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
{
    bool valid = false;
    byte[] keyBytes = myAes.Key;
    Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(true);

    string key = utf8WithoutBom.GetString(keyBytes);
    byte[] outputBytes = utf8WithoutBom.GetBytes(key);

    if (myAes.Key.Length == outputBytes.Length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myAes.Key.Length; i++) {
            if (outputBytes[i] == keyBytes[i]) {
                valid = true;
            }

            else {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (valid == true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Succes");
    }

    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        throw new Exception("The keys do not match.");
    }
}
```

**Result:**
 - Output: byte[] with a size between 50~54 `Error`
 - Desired Output: byte[32] with the same data as the original array `Succes`

**Question:**
 Why are the contents of the output byte array different from the original byte array?

Comment: You are comparing one byte[] to another by == which will always return false if the instances are not same. So even though the byte array contents are most probably the same here, you fail.

Comment: I wanted to ask the database field size, because putting the Key and IV using ASCII encoding will make them, just jumbled text. String is not a good type to store bytes, but there is BitConverter.ToString() for example, which will create a more readable string like F7-04-A1-84-...., and it is not only better at being readable, it is also convertible back to byte[] without any encoding issues

Comment: Oh here it comes then :) Can I suggest a better way to store your keys? Like the one in my second comment?

Comment: I think your assumptions are wrong. The utf8 conversion you try will only work when keyBytes contains valid utf8 data. But not every possible byte array does that. If keyBytes is contains invalid data, already the byte[] -> string conversion produces nonsense (or some fallback value). Converting that back gives the byte array of those fallback values.

Comment: Use Base64 or similar to encode an arbitrary bunch of bytes to a string, not UTF8/UTF-anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from `byte[] -> string -> byte[]` will only work when the initial byte array contains a valid utf8 content. Not every 32 byte array does that.

If the original array contains invalid data, the byte[] -> string conversion will already return some fallback data and a second conversion will convert those fallback values to their corresponding bytes.

If you want to encode an arbitrary byte array into a string, use [Base64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) or some other general data encoding, but not utf8.